# How to make notifications dismiss after delay vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Notifications don't dismiss by themselves:
[image]

How to force them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode does not allow it.

There was a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23684) for it, and [the answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1992) was to show notifications as popups.